# Get multiple values through an AJAX query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hey guys, I am very new to AJAX and and working on a rating script, but I want to be able to pass multiple values back into my ajax function :

Right now it runs a to a php script called ratings, where it takes the total value of votes / votes and multiplies it by the width of each start to get an accurate current rating. What I'd like to do is also pass back the amount of votes so I can display them. I know how I could do this by making another function but that seems redundant and not very efficient.

My question is, is it possible to pass back not only the width (value / votes * 22) for my rating box, but also the total # of votes in 1 query. If not the better question would it be better to pass back a string in jquery that already has the votes & value, and do the width calculation with java script ?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    getRating();
    function getRating(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../includes/rating.php",
    data: "action=get&bookid="+$("#current").attr("value"),
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function($rating) {
    $("#current").css({ width: "" + $rating });
    },
    error: function(result) {
    alert("Error");
    }

});
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can pass back both values. Just send JSON using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode) instead of text.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getRating();
    function getRating(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "../includes/rating.php",
    data: "action=get&bookid="+$("#current").attr("value"),
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $("#current").css({ width: "" + data.rating });
        $("#votes").html(data.votes);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert("Error");
    }

});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your struggling to passback multiple values in one callback you could try inserting a random character (like a #, something your not going to use) inbetween the values then split it on the server side. For example.

**Client Side...**

```
var callback = value1##value2##value3;
```

**Server Side...**

```
$values = split($callback, "##");

$value1 = $values[0];
$value2 = $values[1];
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I think using JSON would generally be better than coming up with a home-grown way to encode many values in a string

Answer (score 1):

Since the width is a derived value based on the number of votes, I would pass the number of votes and do the math in Javascript.